# Why does border-radius cause huge style changes on buttons in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

This is really really weird:

Without anything in chrome buttons look like this:

```
<button>Test</button>
```

[image]

However when you throw in the slightest of border-curvature, the css dramatically shifts to

```
<button style="border-radius:1px">Test</button>
```

[image: button]

Event More noticeable is the `button:active` css changes....

How is it that so many properties can change by adding styling to an object? 
is there even such a thing as a css selector based on styling?

ie. `button:styled{}`?

here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vya24rhw/

Comment: See the *Computed Styles* tab. When there is no `border-radius` set, WebKit uses the default `button` value for the `-webkit-appearance` property and when there is a `border-radius` set, it gets reset to `none`. I guess it is the UA's own way of saying that *this one* (the one that has a `border-radius` set) is a custom styled button or something of that sort. I don't have enough information on the *why* part to post this as an answer.

Comment: This WebKit Blog article actually states that setting background or border properties will disable the default look of buttons - https://webkit.org/blog/28/buttons/. I guess that this is enough info to post an answer and so I will post one shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are seeing  a big difference is because when there is no `border-radius` set, the UA (WebKit) assigns the value for the `-webkit-appearance` property as `button` whereas when there is a `border-radius` set, it resets it to `none`. It seems like the `button` appearance has some specific style settings which are not applied when the appearance is set to `none`. This can be viewed from the *Computed Styles* tab in the Developer Console.

As stated in [this WebKit blog article](https://webkit.org/blog/28/buttons/) dated 7<sup>th</sup> October 2005, there are three appearance constants for buttons namely, `push-button` (which is used by `<input type="submit" .../>`), `bevel-button` and `button` (which is used by the `<button>` element). When an appearance constant is set, the element continues to use the pre-defined appearance settings unless we explicitly reset the `appearance` value to `none` or use our own background and/or border properties. In my opinion, this explains the reason for the difference that we are seeing.

*Note: The blog article doesn't explicitly specify `border-radius` but I am considering border properties to cover the entire spectrum of all properties relating to border and its styling.*